# How do we use two contextual filter because when i use two contextual filter it only filter from first filter second contextual filter is ignored

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-8, drupal-contextual-filters

I have a view with two contextual filters I want to filter from both filter but it only filters by the first contextual filter. The second contextual filter is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If trying to filter from url then need to pass 2 parameters in Url i.e
  example.com/arg1/arg2.
- If using taxonomy field then need to enable *allow multiple values* to able to use multiple values in the form of 1+2+3 (for OR) or 1,2,3 (for AND). If You have another Contextual filter configured, you can separate the query with "/".

For more details can refer -https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77392/multiple-contextual-filters